# AppDelegate how to target navigation controller when root controller is tab bar controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

My root view controller is a tab controller with 3 tabs.

Tabs A and B are standard view controllers, C is a chain of navigation controller / view controllers.

I would like to `popToRootViewController` (is this the right method in this case? or `popToViewController` ?) the C tab from `AppDelegate`.

I have tried

```
self.window.rootViewController.navigationController
```

But it gives nothing, probably because the navigation controller exists in only one tab.

Comment: If you don't know how to access the controllers in the tabs, I suggest you look at the UITabBarController class reference, and review its properties; there aren't that many of them. You should be able to find the one you need.

Comment: I can access it from the tabs, just not from the AppDelegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `rootViewController` is a `UITabBarController` then `rootViewController.navigationController` won't work since your tabbar does not have a navigation controller.

What you want to do is probably using `popToRootViewController` on the view controller which is the third tab of the TabbarController. (You have to be sure that this controller is an `UINavigationController`)

Something like that should work :

```
UITabBarController *tabbarController = (UITabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navController = tabbarController.viewControllers[2];
[navController popToRootViewController];
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but the controller of the third tab is a standard UIViewController. I have no file linked directly linked to a navigation controller, they are inserted via storyboard. Would it still be possible ?

Comment: @kursus, you need to clarify what you mean. In your question, you say that the third tab is a "chain of navigation controller / view controllers". Doesn't that mean the controller directly linked to the tab bar controller is a navigation controller?

Comment: Yes it means that sorry, I just had to add a custom class for my navigationController and link it in storyboard. So AppDelegate is not necessary anymore. Thanks !